# How do I avoid hard coded values in Apex

Tags: apex

I need to create a set of related records after the main record is created.  Each record will have different default data.  I am setting up a predefined service schedule with dates in the future all with different prices and quantities.

Where can I store this predefined data that I will then use to create the records.  Do I just hard code it in the Apex.  I would prefer to put it in a place that the users can change it and then I just read from that location via code and create the records.  My question is what options do I have to store the data or must I hardcode it.

Example:

When they add a contract it should auto populate with the following related contract line items:

Service A, Weekly, $45, 2, Start Date = Today()
Service B, Monthly, $120, 12, Start Date = Today()
Service C, Quarterly, $400, 3, Start Date = Today()
Service D, Annually, $1200, 1, Start Date = Today()

Comment: There are a lot of options to hold the data - a custom object to hold it or use custom settings would be simple examples.

Comment: This is the obvious answer.  More specifically Custom MetaData Types.  Thanks @DaveHumm  If you put this in the form of an Answer I will upvote it and select it as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've used before is storing all those changing values on Custom Setting. Then Create a visualforce page that allow's whoever will take care of those values to have all of them summarized on one page, where each section has its related values.

This way you have a centralized way to manage all those changing values without having to touch your code and not even in need of an admin to be changing values of Labels or custom settings, but the user itself even without any technical knowledge can do it through the interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you truely want to avoid hardcoding, you can always create an extra custom 'configuration' object containing all the information you would require.

Keep in mind you would need some unique identifier to link these objects to the services (eg unique names) - otherwise you might end up hardcoding the ID's of the configuration object which doesnt bring us a step further.